# Why are my images not appearing in firefox?

Tags: html, image, firefox, alt

So I'm using the following code to display an image:

```
<img id='fb'
src="D:/Users/sel0010/Documents/Cadets/Webmaster/Photos/Icons/fblogo.png" 
width="25" 
height="25" 
alt=" Facebook  | " />
</a>
```

When I test my site on Google Chrome I can see it same as on Internet Explorer however when I try on Firefox nothing appears except for what is written under `alt=""`. I'm testing on `Google Chrome Version 26.0.1410.43` m, `IE 9.0.8.8112.16421` and `Firefox version 7.0.1`.

I am really confused, especially with IE working so any help would be amazing,

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a relative path? For instance: `src="fblogo.png"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Two Solutions**

1. Use a relative path:

   ```
   <img id='fb' src="Icons/fblogo.png" width="25" height="25" alt=" Facebook  | " />
   ```
2. Prefix `file:///` for local images:

   ```
   <img id='fb' src="file:///D:/Users/sel0010/Documents/Cadets/Webmaster/Photos/Icons/fblogo.png" width="25" height="25" alt=" Facebook  | " />
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You should use file:// and also add a space before src

Change:

```
<img id='fb'src="D:/Users/sel0010/Documents/Cadets/Webmaster/Photos/Icons/fblogo.png" width="25" height="25" alt=" Facebook  | " /></a>
```

To:

```
<img id='fb' src="file://D:/Users/sel0010/Documents/Cadets/Webmaster/Photos/Icons/fblogo.png" width="25" height="25" alt=" Facebook  | " /></a>
```